# SharePoint Online - Automate a weekly file copy in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, custom-timer-job, copy-item

I am currently working on SharePoint Online and the requirement is to copy a particular document from one document library to another document library. This copy has to be scheduled every week on a particular day.

For example "SharePoint.xlsx" is one of many documents in a "SharePoint1" document library and is updated frequently. This document needs to be copied to "SharePoint2" document library every Monday. Multiple copies of that document are to be created appended with YYYYMMDD . Document should be named as SharePointYYYYMMDD.xlsx everytime its copied and there should be multiple versions of that document with out replacing the previously copied one.

I found this document online, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2014/04/07/sharepoint-timer-jobs-running-as-windows-azure-web-jobs/. But we dont have an azure instance.

Please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you rightly mentioned, Azure WebJobs would be the ideal candidate to fulfill your requirement. But since you dont have the subscription, you can do it from your own machines connected to internet.

I would suggest creation of a Console application and schedule it to run using Windows Scheduler. You can run it from your local machine or from a Server connected to Internet.

You can follow the below mentioned steps :

[image]

[image]

Here, configure it to run weekly, screenshot has a daily scheduled task

[image]

Here, you can give the path to your console application's exe file.

[image]

Once everything is set up, our scheduler will begin to run. You can test run it manually as well

Comment: Thanks a lot for you response. Can you please also help to modify the code in [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2014/04/07/sharepoint-timer-jobs-running-as-windows-azure-web-jobs/ ] to copy a document to a new folder with in one document library.

Comment: Glad i could help, could you please mark it as answer ?  Regarding the question asked here in comment, it is different from what you asked, so you can ask another question here (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) where I or somebody else can also answer it. Also related to that, you can check out my answer here (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/201511/8068) and here (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203267/serverunauthorizedaccessexception-issue-with-copyto-method-in-sharepoint-clien/203283#203283)

Comment: Hello Gautham, I have added another question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208195/sharepoint-online-copy-a-document-to-another-folder-with-in-a-document-library , If you have some time,  Can you please look in to it?