# how to copy files from one document library to another in sharepoint using jsom

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, content-query-web-part

i have a site collection named 'practice'.in which i have created a document library named 'doclib1'.i have created another document library called 'doclib2'.i want to copy the items( text,pdf,images) of doclib1 to doclib2 using jquery or javascript or REST.plz help and provide the complete code.

Answer (score 5):

```
function copyFiles(sourceLib, destLib){

var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var folderSrc = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(sourceLib);
context.load(folderSrc,'Files');
context.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
        console.log("Got the source folder right here!");
        var files = folderSrc.get_files();
        var e = files.getEnumerator();
        var dest = []; 
        while (e.moveNext()) {
            var file = e.get_current();
            var destLibUrl = destLib + "/" + file.get_name();
            dest.push(destLibUrl); //delete this when we're happy we got the file paths right
            file.copyTo(destLibUrl, true);
        }
        console.log(dest); //delete this when we're happy we got the file paths right
        context.executeQueryAsync(function() { console.log("Files moved successfully!");}, function(sender, args) {console.log("error: ") + args.get_message()});
        }, 
    function(sender, args){console.log("Sorry, something messed up: " + args.get_message());}
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
//Usage:
var sourceLibrary = 'Source Library';
var destLibrary = 'Dest Library';

copyFiles(sourceLibrary, destLibrary);
```

Reference - [Move files from one document lib to another](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114033/how-do-i-move-files-from-one-document-library-to-another-using-jsom)

Comment: Works like a charm! But only inside one web. For copiyng between webs we cannot use file.CopyTo(

Comment: @GennadyG - check the answer in this link :) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203267/serverunauthorizedaccessexception-issue-with-copyto-method-in-sharepoint-clien/203283#203283

Comment: Hi Gautam! Thank You! Used example with SPServices from here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91210/copy-document-from-one-site-to-another

Answer (score 1):

Hi below is the code to upload the document to the library and to access the file from library you can just use direct URL of the document.
this code was taken from MSDN article and url of the page is as below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn769086.aspx

```
'use strict';

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    // Check for FileReader API (HTML5) support.
    if (!window.FileReader) {
        alert('This browser does not support the FileReader API.');
    }
});

// Upload the file.
// You can upload files up to 2 GB with the REST API.
function uploadFile() {

    // Define the folder path for this example.
    var serverRelativeUrlToFolder = '/shared documents';

    // Get test values from the file input and text input page controls.
    var fileInput = jQuery('#getFile');
    var newName = jQuery('#displayName').val();

    // Get the server URL.
    var serverUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;

    // Initiate method calls using jQuery promises.
    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    var getFile = getFileBuffer();
    getFile.done(function (arrayBuffer) {

        // Add the file to the SharePoint folder.
        var addFile = addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer);
        addFile.done(function (file, status, xhr) {

            // Get the list item that corresponds to the uploaded file.
            var getItem = getListItem(file.d.ListItemAllFields.__deferred.uri);
            getItem.done(function (listItem, status, xhr) {

                // Change the display name and title of the list item.
                var changeItem = updateListItem(listItem.d.__metadata);
                changeItem.done(function (data, status, xhr) {
                    alert('file uploaded and updated');
                });
                changeItem.fail(onError);
            });
            getItem.fail(onError);
        });
        addFile.fail(onError);
    });
    getFile.fail(onError);

    // Get the local file as an array buffer.
    function getFileBuffer() {
        var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (e) {
            deferred.resolve(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e.target.error);
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileInput[0].files[0]);
        return deferred.promise();
    }

    // Add the file to the file collection in the Shared Documents folder.
    function addFileToFolder(arrayBuffer) {

        // Get the file name from the file input control on the page.
        var parts = fileInput[0].value.split('\\');
        var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

        // Construct the endpoint.
        var fileCollectionEndpoint = String.format(
                "{0}/_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/files" +
                "/add(overwrite=true, url='{2}')",
                serverUrl, serverRelativeUrlToFolder, fileName);

        // Send the request and return the response.
        // This call returns the SharePoint file.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileCollectionEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: arrayBuffer,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length": arrayBuffer.byteLength
            }
        });
    }

    // Get the list item that corresponds to the file by calling the file's ListItemAllFields property.
    function getListItem(fileListItemUri) {

        // Send the request and return the response.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: fileListItemUri,
            type: "GET",
            headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
        });
    }

    // Change the display name and title of the list item.
    function updateListItem(itemMetadata) {

        // Define the list item changes. Use the FileLeafRef property to change the display name. 
        // For simplicity, also use the name as the title. 
        // The example gets the list item type from the item's metadata, but you can also get it from the
        // ListItemEntityTypeFullName property of the list.
        var body = String.format("{{'__metadata':{{'type':'{0}'}},'FileLeafRef':'{1}','Title':'{2}'}}",
            itemMetadata.type, newName, newName);

        // Send the request and return the promise.
        // This call does not return response content from the server.
        return jQuery.ajax({
            url: itemMetadata.uri,
            type: "POST",
            data: body,
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-length": body.length,
                "IF-MATCH": itemMetadata.etag,
                "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
            }
        });
    }
}

// Display error messages. 
function onError(error) {
    alert(error.responseText);
}
```

Few more links are as below.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uksharepoint/2013/04/20/uploading-files-using-the-rest-api-and-client-side-techniques/

http://geekswithblogs.net/ThorvaldBoe/archive/2014/06/06/how-to-upload-files-to-a-sharepoint-2013-document-library.aspx