# ServerUnauthorizedAccessException Issue with CopyTo() method in Sharepoint Client Side Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I'm trying to copy over a publishing page across the Pages List from a source site-collection to a destination site-collection. All works well but when the control hits the `context.ExecuteQuery()` method, it gives me a **`ServerUnauthorizedAccess`** Exception.

The additional information being:

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource.

```
sourceFile.CopyTo(desinationUrl, true);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

The context mentioned above is the context in the source context. I'm passing in the credentials as follows:

```
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("<userId>", <SecureStringPassword>);
```

Is there anything in additional that I'd have to configure anywhere?

Comment: here the client context for the destination site need to be created and used in the Ctx.ExecuteQuery() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CopyTo only works if you want to copy with the same site collection. If you want to copy across site collections, try below code:

```
public void CloneSitePages(string srcUrl, string srcLibrary, string destUrl, string userName, SecureString pwd)
{
string srclibraryname = string.Empty;
string fileName = string.Empty;
string folderPath = string.Empty;
int id = 0;
try
{
    ClientContext srcContext = new ClientContext(srcUrl);
    ClientContext destContext = new ClientContext(destUrl);
    srcContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, pwd);

    Web srcWeb = srcContext.Web;
    List srcList = srcWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=’RecursiveAll’></View>";
    ListItemCollection itemColl = srcList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    srcContext.Load(itemColl);
    FieldCollection fields = srcList.Fields;
    srcContext.Load(fields);
    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();
    destContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, pwd);

    Web destWeb = destContext.Web;
    destContext.Load(destWeb);
    destContext.ExecuteQuery();
    string _path = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl;
    if (itemColl.Count > 0)
    {
    srclibraryname = itemColl[0].FieldValues["FileDirRef"].ToString();
    string[] srcurlSplit = srclibraryname.Split('/');
    srclibraryname = srcurlSplit[srcurlSplit.Count()-1];
    foreach (ListItem doc in itemColl)
    {
        if (doc.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
        {
            fileName = doc["FileRef"].ToString();
            string[] fileNames = fileName.Split(new string[] { srclibraryname }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            int lastRef = fileNames.Count()-1;
            fileName = fileNames[lastRef];
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = doc.File;
            srcContext.Load(file);
            srcContext.ExecuteQuery();
            FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, file.ServerRelativeUrl);
            string serverRelevantUrl = _path + "/" + srclibraryname + fileName;
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, serverRelevantUrl, fileInfo.Stream, true);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File spfile = destContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelevantUrl);
            ListItem item = spfile.ListItemAllFields;
            destContext.Load(item);
            destContext.ExecuteQuery();
            id = item.Id;

            //update the properties to the current page
            List oList = destContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(srcLibrary);
            ListItem oListItem = oList.GetItemById(id);
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count; i++)
            {
            Field fieldTemp = fields[i];
            string InternalName = fieldTemp.InternalName;
                if ((!fieldTemp.ReadOnlyField) && (fieldTemp.InternalName != "Attachments") && (fieldTemp.InternalName != "ContentType"))
                {
                oListItem[InternalName] = doc[InternalName];
                }
            }
            oListItem.Update();
            destContext.ExecuteQuery();
            //Publish the page            
            oListItem.File.CheckIn("Migrated", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
            oListItem.File.Publish("Migrated");
            destContext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
        else if (doc.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.Folder)
        {
            folderPath = doc["FileRef"].ToString();
            string[] fileNames = folderPath.Split(new string[] { srclibraryname }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            int lastRef = fileNames.Count()-1;
            folderPath = fileNames[lastRef];
            folderPath = folderPath.TrimStart(new Char[] { '/' });
            var folder = CreateFolder(destContext.Web, srcLibrary, folderPath);
        }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

public Folder CreateFolder(Web web, string listTitle, string fullFolderPath)
{
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullFolderPath))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("fullFolderPath");
    var list = web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
return CreateFolderInternal(web, list.RootFolder, fullFolderPath);

}
private Folder CreateFolderInternal(Web web, Folder parentFolder, string fullFolderPath)
{
    var folderUrls = fullFolderPath.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string folderUrl = folderUrls[0];
    var curFolder = parentFolder.Folders.Add(folderUrl);
    web.Context.Load(curFolder);
    web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
    if (folderUrls.Length > 1)
    {
    var folderPath = string.Join("/", folderUrls, 1, folderUrls.Count() – 1);
    return CreateFolderInternal(web, curFolder, folderPath);
    }
    return curFolder;
}
```

Reference - [SPFile.CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms471128.aspx)

[Copy pages across site collection](http://jenkinsblogs.com/2016/07/27/clone-or-copy-sharepoint-pagessites-pages-library-files-folders-and-webparts-from-one-site-to-another-using-csom/)